# sed print lines with case insensitive matches

Tags: sed

Given the input

```
From fairest creatures we desire the increase,
That The reby the rose might never die,
Placeholders don't exist
But as tHe riper should by time decease,
```

I'd like to match the lines with case-insensitive variations of `the`, so it should also obtain the line with `The reby` and `tHe riper` above. I want to use `sed`to achieve this. I tried the command

`sed -n "/\bthe\b/ip"`

But it printed

```
p
p
p
```

If I try `sed -n "/\bthe\b/pi"` it prints

```
From fairest creatures we desire the increase,
That The reby the rose might never die,

But as tHe riper should by time decease,
```

So it's close, but it has the empty line. How can I remove it and get only the lines I want?

Comment: Lower case `i` represents the insert command, the case insensitive flag for a regexp  is upper case `I`. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this pattern: `sed -n '/\bthe\b/Ip'` which uses an upper-case i instead of a lower-case one. I've tested it using GNU sed and it seemed to work.

The documentation is partially ambiguous when it lists the possible flags (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Case_002dinsensitive-matching):

```
I
i

    The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which makes sed match regexp in a case-insensitive manner.
```

It becomes a little more precise later on, though:

```
/regexp/I
\%regexp%I

    The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which causes the regexp to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

    In many other programming languages, a lower case i is used for case-insensitive regular expression matching. However, in sed the i is used for the insert command (see insert command).
```